# Set divs opacity related to scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm trying to set the opacity of a series of divs  based on their individual proximity to scrollbar position.

This is what I have so far - http://jsfiddle.net/jGeYg/1/

I've managed to set the opacity to 0 when you are at the top of the window and it raise to 1 as you get to the top of div.

What I'm trying to acheive is for it not to start raising in opacity until you are 50px above the div and hit full opacity when you are at the top of the div. Essentially it's range where opacity changes is

```
$('div').position().top - 50 -> $('div').position().top //psuedo code
```

I don't want to use a plugin. I'm having trouble with the math rather than the code.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your second to last sentence. Are you saying opacity should be 0 when the top of the div is 50px from the bottom of the viewport, and then the opacity should be 1 when the top of the div is 0px from the top of the viewport? If I understand correctly, please consider the user experience when the viewport height is adjusted.

Comment: I want the opacity of the div to be 1 when the top of your viewport is 50px above the div. Re UX - it's just an experiment, shan't be any users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/b9ZCk/3/
I've added some debug text to show the position and opacity.

Comment: That's almost it, but it seems the opacity is rising before you hit the cut off point of 50px. I want it to stay at 0 until you are 50 px above the top of the div. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: When the top or bottom reaches 50px?

Comment: Top of the viewport is above the top of the div

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the desired effect that you want.. but try and let me know,

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.block').each(function(index) {
        if (($(this).offset().top-st) < 50) {
            $(this).css({
                'opacity': (0 + (st / $(this).offset().top))
            });
        } else {
            $(this).css({'opacity': 0.1});
        }
    })
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/jGeYg/5/